# How to use VBA to propagate multiple headers in a single column?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sheets("Sheetname").Range("A3:C3") = Array("header 1", "header 2", "header 3")
```

The above will output those header names in columns A-C in Row 3 horizontally.

```
Sheets("Sheetname").Range("A4:A6") = Array("header x", "header y", "header z")
```

Logically if I wanted to run down a single column over multiple rows the above code seems correct. However, the output ends up being the first header name "header x" being repeated in A4, A5, A6.

Example:

```
header x
header x
header x
```

Instead of:

```
header x
header y
header z
```

Clearly I need to transpose the array to run vertically vs. horizontally. However, I cannot seem to find, via google et al., how to do this using the sort of syntax noted above. Everything posted seems to be making a more "formal array first" as per the following example from Stack:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim a(1 To 3)

    a(1) = "a"
    a(2) = "b"
    a(3) = "c"

    Range("A1:A3").Value = a  'all "a"

    Range("A1:C1").Value = a  'works, because left-to-right is the default

    Range("A1:A3").Value = Application.Transpose(a) 'works

End Sub
```

Is there any way to transpose the array directly in the sheets command?

Comment: The last example in the sample code you showed works (as it says in the comment), so your code needs to be `Sheets("Sheetname").Range("A4:A6") = Application.Transpose(Array("header x", "header y", "header z"))`

Comment: Thank you...I am not sure what I did wrong the first time. I could not get that to work earlier--was getting out of bounds--but in retrying it, it has transposed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Sheets("Sheetname").Range("A4:A6") = Application.Transpose(Array("header x", "header y", "header z"))
```

The above code has worked as, suggested by YoWE3K, in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = Array("1", "2", "3")
Range("A1:A3").Value = Application.Transpose(a)
```